# How do I "claim" a GitHub repo? Or find out the owner?

Tags: github

About 18 months ago I wrote [some code](https://github.com/ghettonet/GhettoNet) and stuck it on GitHub.  The [commits](https://github.com/ghettonet/GhettoNet/commits/master) there are under my name.  And I if I log in and then click on "andrew cooke" (from a commit message) I end up at [a page](https://github.com/andrewcooke) which says "this is you".  So it's me, I guess.  But the "member from" date is Feb this year.

And on that same page it says I have 0 public and 0 private repos.  So did I create the repo as someone else?  Who?  How would I find out and claim it back?  Alternatively, am I misunderstanding something in the GitHib interface?

It wasn't a great project, but it was mine.  I am about to start another, but would like to use the same account, and I am confused.

[**update**: links likely broken as i have used the answer to move the project to my new account]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repository you linked to is owned by the user [ghettonet](https://github.com/ghettonet). The commits are linked to your "andrewcooke" account by email address. Your "andrewcooke" account does not own the `ghettonet/GhettoNet` repository.

Did you perhaps create the "ghettonet" account and then forget about it? Have you tried password recovery on *that* account?

Comment: ah, thanks.  that sounds very likely.  and now i see it's user/project top left.

Comment: so i guess the easiest thing for me to do is fork that into my andrewcooke account, recover the ghettonet password, and then zap the ghettonet account?  (will mark you correct once time limit expires...)